# Pole Order and Residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let function $f(z)$ be analytic in $0 < |z| < R$ and assume that $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $0$. What kind of singularity does function $g(z) = f(z^3)$ has at $0$? Find the residue of the function $g(z)$ at $z_0 = 0$.

Comment: What are some of your thoughts??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if f has a pole of order n at z=0 then:

f(z) := 1/z^n,

then we have that

g(z) = f(z^3) = 1/(z^3)^n = 1/z^3n,

thus g(z) has a pole of order 3n at z=0.

For the residue if we set A(z) := 1, then, noting that A is holomorphic at 0 and it is defined at z=0 we can compute the residue as

Res(g, 0) = A(0)^(3n-1)/(3n-1)! = 0

where the "A(0)^(3n-1)" bit indicates differentiating A(z) 3n-1 times and then plugging 0 into it.